# How to compare and correct each value in dataframe_1's column with all values in each other dataframe_2's columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe_1 (df1) and dataframe_2 (df2) like below:

df1:

```
    uuid          idx    name    type 
0   123abx-...    001    DN       A
1   3124ed-...    002    HN       A
2   125sqe-...    003    HCM      A
3   3123ew-...    004    TD       B
```

df2:

```
    code   name      type 
0   001    DN         A
2   003    TPM        A  
3   004    TD         A
4   006    HN         A
5   007    BD         B
```

I have to update df1 (which is created many years ago) by using df2 to compare, the logic is:

- Must keep the same uuid from df1 (for example: the existed record for example 'TD' change type from B to A then just only update its type field)
- Exmaple 'DN': If df1['idx'] == df2['code'] then compare if df1['name'] == df2['name'] in same row then keep the same value
- Example 'HN': If df1['idx'] <> df2['code'] but df1['name'] == df2['name'] then update its new idx
- Example 'HCM': If df1['idx'] == df2['code'] but df1['name'] <> df2['name'] then append the new record to df1
- And finally for example 'BD': all new records from df2 which can not find any 'idx' exists in df2['code'] column and 'name' exits in df2['name'] column then do the same above - append all new records to df1.

So the output modified df1 is:

```
    uuid          idx    name    type 
0   123abx-...    001    DN       A
1   3124ed-...    007    HN       A
2   125sqe-...    003    HCM      A
3   3123ew-...    004    TD       A
4   na            003    TPM      A
5   na            007    BD       B
```

Please help me, many thanks to your help <3

Comment: Idx for HN is 007? Are you sure?

Comment: Hahaha I make it simple for demo 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge the two dataframes on `name`. Now for each column pairs `('type', 'type_')` and `('idx', 'code')`, combine values from `df1` to `df2` only if `df2` is `NaN` and set the result to `df1` columns:

```
out = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='name', how='outer', suffixes=('', '_'))
out['type'] = out['type_'].combine_first(out['type'])
out['idx'] = out['code'].combine_first(out['idx'])

out = out[df1.columns]
```

```
>>> out
     uuid  idx name type
0  123abx  001   DN    A
1  3124ed  006   HN    A
2  125sqe  003  HCM    A
3  3123ew  004   TD    A
4     NaN  003  TPM    A
5     NaN  007   BD    B
```